# how to resolve body-parser module disabled looking in node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My API doesn't work well and I've noticed that the `body-parser` module seems somehow disabled and I didn't find anything about it, please see the attached photo. Is there any solution?

[vscode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKuTN.jpg)

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var cors = require('cors');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var Users = require("./models/Users");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:  true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/usersDB';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});
```

Comment: Those strike through lines indicate that that module/code you're using is/has been marked as deprecated - take a look at the [VSCode release notes from Aug 2020](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_deprecated-tag-support-for-javascript-and-typescript) for more info.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/480b1cfe29af19c070f4ae96e0d598c099f42a12/index.js#L84-L91) for that module, you can safely ignore the strike through as you do not directly call the `bodyParser` function.

Comment: thanks I changed it to newer version, const express = require('express');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
but still getting undefined for req.body.password

Comment: That second issue seems to be unrelated to the original issue you're facing - could you please post a new question?

Comment: ok it is solved by sending as raw format in postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this instead of pody-parser resolved the problem:

```
const express = require('express');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
```